# How to copy error in Android studio like in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I would like to copy the error how is shown in the Image below. I did this very quickly with Eclipse putting simply the cursor above

[image]

Comment: did you resolved it?

Comment: i did not resolve, still no answer

Comment: I also need an answer.

Comment: Android Studio is very aggravating to use.  It tries to be too slick for its own good. I wonder if there is mailing list to vent complaints?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can Copy Error Message By click on the part of line that error happened, you can seeing error message on status bar, then Right Click On The Left Of Status bar and select copy.

[image]

Also, You can run application and copy error by right click on error of message toolbar

[image]

Comment: You can Copy Error Message By click on the part of line that error happened, you can seeing error message on status bar, then Right Click On The Left Of Status bar and select copy. yes it is the correct and easier solution!

Comment: I don't see the error in the status bar, and compiling doesn't produce the same error message.

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this annoying problem. So in Android Studio, after release the left mouse button, the highlight will be cancelled. I tried to hold the left button while pressing Ctrl+C, it worked!

Comment: It's best and only one in this post to, allow to copy Ctrl-F1 long message. Thanks a lot!

Comment: works for me, but I have to be quick, as the tooltip goes away on its own after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

After build the project you can see and copy the error message after right click. Please see the following screen shot.

[image]